# Selection Brush is not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

WPF- Selection Brush is not working, I am selecting 'H' in my case but it is not working.
Here is my code :
XAML :

```
<TextBox Text="Hello" Height="49"  Name="textBox2" Width="547" />
```

C#

```
textBox2.SelectionStart = 0;
textBox2.SelectionLength = 1;
textBox2.SelectionBrush = Brushes.Red;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        textBox2.Focus();
        textBox2.SelectionStart = 0;
        textBox2.SelectionLength = 1;
        textBox2.SelectionBrush = Brushes.Red;
```

Comment: and is it possible to change the color of selected text ?

Comment: Actually I don't want to focus on textbox2

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to trick the TextBox into thinking it has not lost focus. This way, you're not *actually* moving focus back to the TextBox.

For this to work, you'd have to set focus on the TextBox at least once, like when the user enters the initial text, or by calling textBox2.Focus() from the constructor.

Markup:

```
<TextBox Height="49" x:Name="textBox2" LostFocus="TextBox2_OnLostFocus" />
```

Code-behind:

```
private void TextBox2_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I calling it from keyup event